# Removing an array from an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have an array simmilar to this:

```
$scripts_to_load  = array(
    'css' => array(
        array(
            'name'=>'core-css',
            'path'=>get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'media-query-css',
            'path'=>get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/mediaquery.css'
        ), 
    ),
);
```

**The above is how assets are stored.**

I'd like to writer a function that takes type, `css` or `js` and a name, the type will find either `css` or `js` and then the name will be used to each for a key that matches the `name` key in one of the arrays, if it s found that array will be unset.

So what I have, is nothing accept: `public function remove_asset($type, $name){}`, so If I pass in `remove_asset('css', 'media-query-css')` the array should then look like:

```
$scripts_to_load  = array(
    'css' => array(
        array(
            'name'=>'core-css',
            'path'=>get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')
        ),
    ),
);
```

I am just not sure how to do that ... I can find the `$type` just fine, but its finding the $name that's giving me troubles and then unsetting that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function does what you need:

```
function remove_asset($type, $name, &$scripts_to_load) {
    if( isset($scripts_to_load[$type] ) ) {
        foreach( $scripts_to_load[$type] as $key => $value ) {
            if( !empty( $value['name'] ) && $value['name'] == $name ) {
                unset( $scripts_to_load[$type][$key] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is an control run:

```
$scripts_to_load  = array(
    'css' => array(
        array(
            'name'=>'core-css',
            'path'=>'stylesheet_url'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'media-query-css',
            'path'=>'/assets/mediaquery.css'
        ), 
    ),
);

print_r( $scripts_to_load );
echo "\n";

remove_asset('css', 'media-query-css', $scripts_to_load);

print_r( $scripts_to_load );
echo "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming assets are stored in object property):

```
public function remove_asset($type, $name){
    if(isset($this->assets[$type][$name])) {
        unset($this->assets[$type][$name]);
    }
}
```

This should remove the asset by given type and name.

Oh, and of course, the array of assets should look like this:

```
$this->assets = array(
    'css' => array(
        'css_name1' => 'path_to_css_1',
        'css_name2' => 'path_to_css_2',
    ),
    'js' => array(
        'js_name1' => 'path_to_js_1',
        'js_name2' => 'path_to_js_2',
    )
);
```

Now, if You call:

```
$this->remove_asset('css', 'css_name2');
$this->remove_asset('js', 'js_name1');
```

you should end up with:

```
$this->assets = array(
    'css' => array(
        'css_name1' => 'path_to_css_1',
    ),
    'js' => array(
        'js_name2' => 'path_to_js_2',
    )
);
```

**EDIT**: basically when working with asset properties You want more control to be stored, not only the path, so my suggested (end) array should be:

```
$this->assets = array(
    'css' => array(
        'css_name1' => array(
            'src' => 'path_to_css_1',
            'media' => 'screen',
            'type' => 'text/css',
        ),
        'css_name2' => array(
            'src' => 'path_to_css_2',
            'media' => 'print',
            'type' => 'text/css',
        ),
    ),
    'js' => array(
        'js_name1' => array(
            'src' => 'path_to_js_1',
            'type' => 'text/javascript',
        ),
    ),
    'icon' => array(
        'favicon' => array(
            'href' => 'path_to_favicon',
            'rel' => 'shortcut icon',
        ),
    'meta' => array(/* ... */)
);
```

And the `remove_asset` function will still work.

Comment: this is completely wrong. the array I showed you is how the assets are stored. its the array attached to `$scripts_to_load` Its is not `$key=>array`, it is `$key=>array(array(), array())`. where `$key` is `$type` and `$name` is one of the keys in the `array()` of `arrays()`. please see the OP.

Comment: I am recommending to rework the assets array... In this case the removing/adding of assets is much easier and **You need less loops** when trying to load the assets...